# Where is the link happening between performclick and handleCallBack(Message message) in Android when a button is clicked

Tags: android

Here is the View Class's PerformClick:

```
private final class PerformClick implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        recordGestureClassification(TOUCH_GESTURE_CLASSIFIED__CLASSIFICATION__SINGLE_TAP);
        performClickInternal();
    }
}
```

And here is the Handler's :

```
 public void dispatchMessage(Message msg) {
    if (msg.callback != null) {
        handleCallback(msg);
    } else {
        if (mCallback != null) {
            if (mCallback.handleMessage(msg)) {
                return;
            }
        }
        handleMessage(msg);
    }
}
```

Just wanted to know the how this calls the View's performClick method if a button is clicked. What will be the dynamic structure of the different fields of the message when a button is clicked?

Answer (score 0):

Somehow analyzed it. Its through the callback field of the Message object that is passed to the dispatchMessage(Message message) of the Handler class. Just wanted to confirm. See the image. The callback for the mouse click event is highlighted

[image]